# Where is the official developer guide for Activiti 7.x or Activiti 6.x?

Tags: activiti

Earlier, I used the developer/user guide for Activiti 6.x. I have recently migrated to Activiti 7.x, and I cannot find the user/developer guide for Activiti 7.x (Activiti engine).

I even tried to find the userguide for the previous version, but I couldn't find it either. The URL https://community.alfresco.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.activiti.org%2Fuserguide%2F is not responding.
The developer guide located on https://activiti.gitbook.io/activiti-7-developers-guide/ is not enough.

Where is the official developer guide for Activity 7.x?

Comment: The guide for Activiti Engine 6.x is now available, but I still hope to find a good, detailed guide for Activiti Engine 7.x.

Answer (score -1):

There is one e-book available you can use for reference

https://the-eye.eu/public/Books/IT%20Various/activiti_in_action.pdf

Comment: The year of this book is 2012. The Acitiviti 7.0 was released in Feb 2019. So this book is not suitable